# Broken mobile responsiveness in iOS only

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I'm experiencing a weird issue with the mobile responsive layout of a website.
The address is https://melec.vercel.app/

On desktop using dev tools > responsive, it works correctly, also on any android device you get the correct mobile experience but in iOS devices (tested on 2 iphones) the website renders incorrectly, it seems to have the double of the actual available screen width.

**For reference I'm using tailwindcss, tailwindui and nextjs.**

In this image you can see the scroll bar for horizontal movement.
[image: Picture 1]

Here you can see how I can freely move horizontally, this doesn't happen on dev tools or android devices.
[image: Picture 2]

Also when I press the mobile burger the whole layout shrinks a bit.
[image: Picture 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because the top part "flex-shrink-0 flex items-center".
I entered a "max-width: 100%;".

Comment: Incredible, I have been chasing this issue for 2 days and finally decided it was something else, while all the time it was just a misunderstanding on the flex-shrink-0..... THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: It seems the issue is with the h-full, both changing the flex-shrink-0 or adding a h-8 solves the issue, again, thank you!!
<img className="block lg:hidden h-full py-2" src="/logo-square.png" />